# Dynamically Setting Size of ImageView Android

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am using the following method to dynamically create `Bitmaps` from Drawables and asign them to my ImageViews. This method is called repeatedly. The problem is that I cannot set the size of the Images properly, on different phones it looks different, on my Note 3 it looks big, on my friends galaxy core it looks small.

METHOD

```
 public void setImageView(int i,Integer d, LinearLayout layout ) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    imageView.setMaxHeight(200);
    imageView.setMaxWidth(200);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parms.setMargins(15, 50, 15, 25);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), d));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    layout.addView(imageView);
}
```

USAGE OF METHOD

```
horizontal_scroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_layout);
                setImageView(1, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
                setImageView(2, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
    setImageView(3, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
    setImageView(4, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
    setImageView(5, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
    setImageView(6, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
    setImageView(7, R.drawable.hex_filled, layout);
```

LAYOUT

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:weightSum="100"
tools:context=".City_Search">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/white_lines"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="85"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_listview"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:id="@+id/followed_cities"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_up"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hex_filled"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried different scale type.

from google documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

> CENTER_INSIDE    Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding). The image is then centered in the view.